# Somehow losing these data values Java

Tags: java

Somehow between my constructor setting the values and then calling said values in Main they become null. The code is just supposed to let the user enter the books author, title, and genre, and then display those values.

```
package book;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Book {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public String author;
    public String title;
    public String genre;

    public Book(String author, String title, String genre) {
        String bookAuthor = author;
        String bookTitle = title;
        String bookGenre = genre;
        System.out.println(bookAuthor + bookTitle + bookGenre);
        System.out.println(author + title + genre);
    }

    public Book() {
        String bookAuthor;
        String bookTitle;
        String bookGenre;
    }

    public void setTitle() {
        System.out.print("What is the title of the book? ");
        title = input.nextLine();
    }

    public void setAuthor() {
        System.out.print("Who wrote this book? ");
        author = input.nextLine();
    }

    public void setGenre() {
        System.out.print("What genre category does this book fall under? ");
        genre = input.nextLine();
    }

    public void getAuthor() {
        System.out.printf("\nAuthor: %s", author);
    }

    public void getTitle() {
        System.out.printf("\nTitle: %s", title);
    }

    public void getGenre() {
        System.out.printf("\nGenre: %s", genre);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { //starting point of any Java program
        Book book = new Book(); //create new instance of Book() so that main can modify it
        book.setTitle();
        book.setAuthor();
        book.setGenre();
        Book myBook = new Book(book.author, book.title, book.genre);
        System.out.println(myBook.author + myBook.title + myBook.genre);
        myBook.getAuthor();
        myBook.getTitle();
        myBook.getGenre();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of having getter/setter if your properties are public?

Comment: Why does nobody use the debugger? You don't understand your problem, or why the code behave not exactly you want. Read the code again and maybe you'll understand the problem. If not, read it again and again. If you don't know where you made a mistake use the DEBUGGER. For this silly problems is useless to post a question!

Comment: Remove the Scanner object and all method calls to that object as that has no business being in the Book class. The Book class should just encapsulate the information of one Book, no more and no less. All user interaction code belongs elsewhere, such as in your BookTester class. Also you should give your classes true useful setter methods, ones that take parameters that can be passed in and used to set fields. And give it true getter methods, ones that return values and have no println's within them (except for temporary debugging purposes if needed).

Comment: it is quite confusing to have a  method which is named like a setter but is actually a input procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
public Book(String author, String title, String genre){
    String bookAuthor = author;
    String bookTitle = title;
    String bookGenre = genre;
    System.out.println(bookAuthor + bookTitle + bookGenre);
    System.out.println(author + title + genre);
    }
```

You are declaring local/stack variables in your book constructor and assigning the input parameters to them.  They then go away when the constructor exits, as they are no longer in scope.  I think you mean to do this, and assign the constructor parameters to your objects data members:

```
public Book(String authorIn, String titleIn, String genreIn){
    author = authorIn;
    title = titleIn;
    genre = genreIn;
    }
```

Also, those void getter methods don't make any sense.

Comment: Ah, [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) strikes again. 1+ For the life of me, I couldn't find out what his actual problem was with all the ranting in the question.

Comment: There should be warnings for that:(

Comment: So my problem was that I was creating another variable with the same name that was not permanent like the outer strings? Thanks for explaining it in a clear cut way I could understand. 

Is there something fundamentally wrong with the void getters? I am very new at this and do not know proper programming practices yet.

@Hovercraft thank you for that link

Comment: @MartinJames: most compilers do have warnings for this, for instance that Eclipse will warn you about variable shadowing, but again, the warning is not implement by default. You have to turn it on.

Comment: @Matthew: yes there is something wrong. A getter should return something. For instance `getAuthor()` should be declared to return a String (not void) and should return the author String. It should not print out anything, as that would be the responsibility of the class that calls the getter method. Also, and again, your setters should all have a single parameter and use that parameter to set something. This is all well explained in any introductory Java book or tutorial. Please have a look.

Comment: @Matthew: please have a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html). And again, **please** edit and improve your question. Strive for clarity, not ranting. Clearly describe what you expect your code to do and how it is misbehaving. We want to see useful information that will help us to fully understand your actual problem.

Comment: @Hovercraft that is one of the tutorials I read through almost 50times while working on this program. Assuming I have not is simply being a jerk, not helpful. Thank you for the advice you have given though and I'll look into cleaning up my code.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not coming off well, but writing questions here is a learned skill, something that you will get better with time and effort, but one thing you should strive to do is to remove chuff, and only include that which pertains to the question itself. If you strive for clarity, folks will **understand** your problem, which after all is your goal, as this will lead to solutions. For details, please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions.

Comment: @Matthew: also, please note that our comments are made to do just that, to help you improve the question, again all for the sake of clarity. You were initially ignoring my requests for clarification, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

As OldProgrammer has stated, you need to not shadow variables, but more importantly, get user interaction out of the Book class. It should encapsulate only Book information and all user interaction should go elsewhere. Also the setters and getters should be true setters and getters, i.e, the setter methods set the fields and the getter methods return.

For example of a getter/setter pair, consider the String field foo:

```
private String foo;

// getter
public String getFoo() {
   return foo;
}

// setter 
public void setFoo(String foo) {
   this.foo = foo;
}
```

For example a simple version of Book could look like:

```
public class SimpleBook {
   private String author;
   private String title;

   public SimpleBook(String author, String title) {
      this.author = author;
      this.title = title;
   }

   // getter method returns the field's value
   public String getAuthor() {
      return author;
   }

   // setter method sets the field's value
   public void setAuthor(String author) {
      this.author = author;
   }
   public String getTitle() {
      return title;
   }
   public void setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
   }

   // so the book can be displayed cleanly
   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Book [Author: " + author + ", title: " + title + "]";
   }

}
```

Then user interaction could go into a test class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestSimpleBook {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter an Author: ");
      String author = scanner.nextLine();

      System.out.print("Enter an Title: ");
      String title = scanner.nextLine();

      SimpleBook book = new SimpleBook(author, title);

      System.out.println("Your Book: " + book);

      scanner.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you again for the advice, I'll take it to heart. Going to look into what "this" is and I appreciate pointing out standard practices to me. Sorry if I came off hostile I was already frustrated as can be. This is my second week learning Java and I'd spent around 6hrs going over tuts and looking at other answers before asking here.